# good book for definitions of spectrum and eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, spectral-theory

I am trying to find references for definitions of eigenvalues, eigenfunctions and spectrum of operators any advice??

Comment: What's wrong with the definitions given in literally every introductory linear algebra book ever written?

Comment: I think he wants it in the context of infinite dimensional normed algebras. Any book on functional analysis should do. You could take Walter Rudin's Functional Analysis for instance.

Comment: can you give me some books in linear algebra which include these definitions?

Comment: Please give an example of the introductory books on linear algebra which you've already studied.  It's hard to tell whether your interests lie in undergraduate or graduate level studies.

Answer (score 2):

In general in a book in linear algebra you will only find the definitions of eigenvalues and eigenvectors and not the definition of the spectrum of an operator on a Banach space.

All definitions concerning operator- and spectral- theory can be found for instance in

Walter Rudin's Functional Analysis

or in

the book "Introduction to Functional Analysis" written by A.E. Taylor and D:C: Lay.